# How can i show ListView in Drawerlayout?My app cannot show it

Tags: android, listview, drawerlayout

In my app,i make a ImageView and a ListView in Drawerlayout,But the ListView can not show anyway.
code : the whole project is in [Github](https://github.com/TingYa/Weather)

```
 private String[] datatest = {"naning","beijing","shantou"};
 private ListView chooseCity;
 private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    chooseCity = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.choosecity);
    //侧边栏
    ArrayAdapter chooseCityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datatest);
    Log.d(TAG,"侧边栏adapter");
    chooseCity.setAdapter(chooseCityAdapter);
}
```

The ListView xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settinglayout"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/choosecity"/>
</com.zhy.android.percent.support.PercentLinearLayout>
```

The activity_main.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--主界面-->
        <include layout="@layout/main"/>
        <!--侧边栏-设置菜单-->
        <include layout="@layout/setting"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: only can show the ImageView but not the ListView

Comment: Are you trying to make something like a navigation drawer?